# Is there any particular reason to use a file to configure a logger?

Tags: python, logging

I have a file called "logging.conf" which I use in the "normal" way to configure my Python logger.

But I can't understand why one would want to use a text file in this way when it is possible to configure everything within the code. Surely text files are by their nature more fragile: at the moment I'm testing to make sure it exists, is a file (not a directory), and that reading it in works OK, etc.

It takes as much code to check that the file is OK as it would to just configure in the code. Maybe with a more complex logging setup this wouldn't be so. I have just two handlers: console and rotating file handler.

Maybe it's just historical that people use a file to configure their logger... or maybe there's another explanation?

Comment: i'm not sure; here's my guess(es): possibly if there's something sensitive about the file location, or if this software is meant to be used by others? so the logger configuration file could be ignored by version control if being uploaded to a public repository.

Comment: Ah yes, not a bad thought. But any problems with that file and you might want some compact code for a default setup as a "fallback". I always use this brilliant handler class called ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler, so you have to pip install that (and then make reference to it in the logging.conf file), so it's not like these things necessarily function in complete independence...

Comment: i've used the std lib rotating file handler, but not this concurrent one. thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: Best thing since sliced bread :)